# Bootable Windows USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb

I'm trying to create a windows bootable USB on mac, I used lots of programs to burn the USB but failed. When I connect my "windows bootable USB" to another computer boot from it, the screen says

`no default or UI configuration directive found!`

also on top says something about Linux and I don't understand why Linux appears if it is a windows os
Please Help

Comment: More information is needed. Much more.

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-installer-usb-drive-mac